# D&D4 Boots of rapid motion vs Rock Armor

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, powers

Hello I have a question about some abilities in D&D 4e. Actually I am having the following skill:

Rock Armor Daily minor

> **Effect**: you assume the rock armor stance. Until the stance ends, you
>   are ***slowed*** and gain resistance to all damage equal to your Cha
>   modifier.

And we got the following item:

> Boots of rapid motion
>   **Trigger**: An effect ***slows*** you.
>   **Effect**: You make a saving throw against the triggering effect. On a save, effect ends.

Does it mean that when I use my Rock Armor, I have to make saving throw and if it save I won't be slowed but still have resistance against dmg?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Here's the thing, the slowed and the damage resistance are both part of the *same effect*. By saving against the slowing effect, you'll be saving against the stance itself (which you could end with a minor action if you wanted to). Thus by saving against the stance, you'll exit the stance and lose the damage resistance.

So no, you can't use this to remove the slow and keep the DR. They are part of the same effect and would both end on the save.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the save isn't optional either!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie triggered effects are always optional

Comment: Really! That's counter-intuitive. I guess I should check my character over…